# Using cookie to execute SQL select

Tags: sql, .net, razor, cookies, webmatrix

I am trying to use a cookie in my .NET Razor application to remember a users form field information.

The first time a user submits an enquiry using the form, an entry is inserted into the database, and a GUID is created for that entry. This GUID is then saved as a cookie on the users computer:

```
// Create Enquiry Cookie
HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("BookingReq");
myCookie.Value = bookingguid;
myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
```

The next time a user goes to a different property page, I want to use the GUID in the cookie to pull information out of the database about their last request, and populate the form with the same information.

First I do this:

```
if(Request.Cookies["BookingReq"] != null){
    var breq = db.Query("SELECT * FROM BookingRequests WHERE BookingGUID = @0", Request.Cookies["BookingReq"].Value);
}
```

In theory, this should work, but I am not able to populate the form using the traditional method:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="customerName">Your Name</label>
        <input type="text" value="@breq.CustomerName" class="form-control" id="customerName" name="customerName">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="customerEmail">Email address</label>
        <input class="form-control" value="@breq.CustomerEmail" id="customerEmail" name="customerEmail">
</div>
```

I'm guessing this is because you can't call variables from within an 'if' statement? What are my options here?

I don't want to perform an 'if' statement for every form field unless it's absolutely the last resort.

Comment: Please let us know in what way "i am not able to populate the form". Does it leave them blank? Error? Also, for the first second block of code, is this in the view or the controller?

Comment: I'm actually building this on the asp.net web pages framework, so there's no true distinction between the view an the controller, but the issue is essentially a view problem. the @breq.CustomerEmail value in the form isn't an option, since that variable lives within an 'if' statement. If i take it out of the 'if' statement, then it is an option, but then i'm removing the logic to see if the cookie doesn't exist (which is more often than not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope of you variable `bref` is wrong. You declare it within the if block and this is the only place it can be used. In addition `breq.CustomerName` will fail if breq is null. So the fix would be something like

```
var customerName = "";
var customerEmail = "";
if (Request.Cookies["BookingReq"] != null) {
    var breq = db.Query("SELECT * FROM BookingRequests WHERE BookingGUID = @0", Request.Cookies["BookingReq"].Value);
    //I don't know webmatrix so I don't know what happens to breq if that value doesn't exist - I'll assume it's null
    if (breq != null) {
        customerName = breq.CustomerName;
        customerEmail = breq.CustomerEmail;
    }
}
```

and then in the controls you can use `value="@customerName"` and `value="@customerEmail"`

Comment: makes sense! give me half hour, and i'll put it into action ;)